# Stopping thread with sentinel does not work

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, sentinel

I'm new to multithreading in java and I can't figure out on how to stop a thread. 
I have an `ArrayList` of threads which I want to stop.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class PrimeThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while(flag) {
        //do some stuff
        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        flag = false;
    }
...
}
Class MainClass {
    public static void stopPrimeThreads() {
        for(int i=0; i<primeThreadList.size(); i++) primeThreadList.get(i).cancel();
    }
}
```

I try to stop the thread by setting the `flag` variable to `false`. The `flag` variable is a `volatile boolean` declared in the class itself. I also tried to use an outer class variable as sentinel but that did not work either. Also a non `volatile` variable does not do the job.
When I use the deprecated `stop()` method I get the behavior I want, but I don't want to use a deprecated method. 
Does anybody has an idea on how to fix this problem? Am I missing something fundamental? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `volatile`. Is `//do some stuff` blocking/long-running thing?

Comment: Yes it's a loop that takes a very long time.

Comment: you'll need to make internal `stuff` execute in smaller steps, so after each step, `flag` is checked.

Comment: Thanks Victor this worked! Because I had a very long loop there the change in the flag variable was not detected I think. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make internal loop something like

```
while (flag) {
   // smaller step 1
   if (!flag) break;
   // so on
}
```

As a side-note, if your internal loop takes very long time, it *may* indicate you using some sub-optimal algorithm. Though, if you working with very large numbers, long calculation times are unavoidable.

Comment: Thanks for this Victor! I accept as soon as it is possible. I use the program to solve a mathematical problem so the long calculation time inside that loop is typical for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have used a non-volatile field, the JIT can optimise the reading of that field away i.e. becuase you don't modify it in your thread.  If you make the field `volatile` it will ensure you change is always seen.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to know why this doesn't work, since you don't provide an SSCCE, but you should simply use interrupt(), which is designed for that, and allows stopping a thread even if it's waiting on some blocking method:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And to stop the thread:

```
thread.interrupt();
```

Of course, whatever the solution you choose, if you have another long-running loop inside the outer loop, the thread won't stop until it checks the value of the interrupted/cancelled flag. Make sure to check the flag as often as possible.

Answer (score 1):

use your **cancel** method not stop on this line...

```
primeThreadList.get(i).stop();
```

like so...

```
primeThreadList.get(i).cancel();
```

Comment: Sorry I do it that way, I forget to rename my stop() to cancel(). I renamed it to avoid confusion with the deprecated stop() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PrimeThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean flag = true;
    public void run() {
        while(flag) {
        //do some stuff
        }
    }
    public void cancel() {
        flag = false;
    }
...
}
Class MainClass {
    public static void stopPrimeThreads() {
        for(int i=0; i<primeThreadList.size(); i++) primeThreadList.get(i).cancel();
    }
}
```